# Merging several json files with a common array element

Tags: arrays, json, merge, jq

I have several groups of json files where each group follows common pattern of data as below:

file 1:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "122"
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 1391,
  "links": {
    "next": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=12&per_page=100",
    "last": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=14&per_page=100"
  }
}
```

file 2:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "211"
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 2391,
  "links": {
    "next": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=22&per_page=100",
    "last": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=24&per_page=100"
  }
}
```

File 3:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "311"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "322"
    },
    {
      "id": 13438719,
      "code": "333"
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 3391,
  "links": {
    "next": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=32&per_page=100",
    "last": "https://api.xxx.com/projects?page=34&per_page=100"
  }
}
```

The above 3 files are sample files of a group and each file in this group has an array element "projects". Other groups have same structure but different array element name.
I need to merge all the files of a group into a single file per group. The output of the above files is expected as:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "122"
    },
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "211"
    },
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "311"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "322"
    },
    {
      "id": 13438719,
      "code": "333"
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 1391
}
```

I used the following jq code to achieve this.

```
jq -s ".[0].projects=([.[].projects]|flatten)|.[0] | del(.links)" file[123].json
```

But I am not happy with this as I have to hard code array element name "projects" in this case. I am looking for a solution where array element name doesn't need to be specified, so I can use that expression for every of similar content file.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: *for every of similar content file* - elaborate the rule for similarity between different files

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest as an example for product related group of files, the array element will be named "products", for order related group of files it will be "orders"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is essentially the same as @jq170727's solution, but packages the key abstraction into a function that may be worthy of your standard jq library:

```
# Gather by key all the values of the objects in a stream
def buckets(stream): reduce stream as $x ({};
  reduce ($x|keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.;
    .[$key] += [$x[$key]] ) );
```

With this in place, the solution becomes simply:

```
buckets(inputs) | map_values(add) | del(.links)
```

#### Standard Library

For example, if your standard jq library is in ~/.jq/jq/jq.jq then you could use the following one-liner:

```
jq -n 'include "jq"; buckets(inputs) | map_values(add) | del(.links)' file{1,2,3}.json
```

#### Addendum re: `total_entries`

OP asked:

> what do I need to do if I don't want to add the total_entries from each of the file, I would like to take the value from the first file only

The following modification of the above program will use the first-encountered value for `total_entries`:

```
buckets(inputs)
| . as $buckets
| map_values(add)
| del(.links) + {total_entries: $buckets["total_entries"][0]}
```

Comment: What purpose map_values(add) serve?  Also if I run the above command, I lose content of first file, addition of -n switch (as per the answer by @jq170727) takes care of it.

Comment: `map_values` is documented in the manual.  Thanks for pointing out that I forgot the -n option. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution assuming your sample data is in `file1.json`, `file2.json` and `file3.json`:

```
$ jq -Mn '
    reduce inputs as $i ({}; 
     reduce ($i|keys[]) as $k (.; .[$k] += $i[$k])) 
  | del(.links)
' file1.json file2.json file3.json
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "122"
    },
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "211"
    },
    {
      "id": 15658857,
      "code": "311"
    },
    {
      "id": 15623456,
      "code": "322"
    },
    {
      "id": 13438719,
      "code": "333"
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 7173
}
```

Note that this adds the values for `total_entries` from each file giving a different total then the one in the requested output.

Comment: `keys_unsorted`?

Comment: @jq170727 I am not able to follow the code, can you please explain? Also if I remove -n switch, it loses content of first file. 
Also, what do I need to do if I don't want to add the total_entries from each of the file, I would like to take the value from the first file only

Comment: @jq170727, I am accepting solution provided by peak as it has answer for another part of my query. Thanks for the nice approach.